# Bootstrap section stacking with above section on mobile screen size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a problem. Everything seemed perfect when I finished `section-3`, but when I started coding `section-4`, it started stacking on `section-3`'s content.

### Code

**HTML**

```
<!-- Start Of SECTİON TREE !-->

    <section class="section-3" id="sec3">
        <div class="tribg">
            <img src="Parts/triangles.png" alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="card-deck">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="card mycards">
                            <img src="Parts/shield.png" alt="" class="img-fluid" width="50px">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h3 class="card-title">DENEME</h3>
                                <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam sint expedita alias, dolorem sapiente culpa distinctio libero saepe. Recusandae numquam aut aliquam, ullam voluptatum placeat quis omnis perspiciatis, distinctio quae eaque nemo consequatur ratione mollitia beatae alias molestiae quod optio ipsa. Totam assumenda, aperiam quae!</p>
                                    <div class="btn btn-primary">DENEME</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="card mycards">
                                    <img src="Parts/shield.png" alt="" class="img-fluid" width="50px">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                    <h3 class="card-title">DENEME</h3>
                                    <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam sint expedita alias, dolorem sapiente culpa distinctio libero saepe. Recusandae numquam aut aliquam, ullam voluptatum placeat quis omnis perspiciatis, distinctio quae eaque nemo consequatur ratione mollitia beatae alias molestiae quod optio ipsa. Totam assumenda, aperiam quae!</p>
                                    <div class="btn btn-primary">DENEME</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="card mycards">
                                <img src="Parts/shield.png" alt="" class="img-fluid" width="50px">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                <h3 class="card-title">DENEME</h3>
                                <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam sint expedita alias, dolorem sapiente culpa distinctio libero saepe. Recusandae numquam aut aliquam, ullam voluptatum placeat quis omnis perspiciatis, distinctio quae eaque nemo consequatur ratione mollitia beatae alias molestiae quod optio ipsa. Totam assumenda, aperiam quae!</p>
                                <div class="btn btn-primary">DENEME</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

<!-- End Of SECTİON TREE !-->

<!-- Start Of SECTİON FOUR !-->

    <section class="section-4">
        <div class="holder"><img src="Parts/shape9.png" alt="" class="img-fluid"></div>
    </section>

<!-- End Of SECTİON FOUR !-->
```

**CSS**

```
/* SECTİON TREE */

.section-3 {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
}


.tribg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 20%;
    z-index: 0;
}

.mycards {
    padding: 60px 100px;
    margin-top: 8rem;
    border-radius: 63px;
    box-shadow: 6px 7px 100px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
    transition: .3s;

}

.mycards p {
    margin-bottom: 6rem;
}

.cardimg {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.mycards:hover {
    transform: translateY(-30px);
}

.gotopanel {
    font-size: 20px;
}

/* End Of SECTİON TREE */

/* SECTİON FOUR */
.section-4 {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Can you please check my answer and tick it as green if it is working for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your css, remove or change height property here:

```
 .section-3    {
            position: relative;
            height: 100vh;
        }

        .section-4    {
            height: 100vh;
        }
```

Comment: @Çağdaşİlhan make it green please then